# how would I make this query in microsoft access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have just recently started working with microsoft access, and have been importing excel spread sheets into separate tables. the content of the tables is similar to following (i will place column names at the top, there would be additional entries below in table, so more names, etc)

```
ID | name | age | and so on
1  | ajw5293 | 22 |
```

and then for an additional table, I have something along the lines of:

```
ID | location | time | grade | and so on
1  | 02364    | 10:50 | A |
```

If I wanted to make a query where I could search for a name, and then have all of the relevant information show up for that name based on the ID (so all of the information in the rows with ID 1 would be retrieved), what do you think would be the best way to go about doing this? I have been searching around for some guidelines on how to do so but have not been able to put together a solution yet unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated though, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a join.

```
SELECT NameTable.ID,[Name],Age,location,[time],[grade],NameTable.[and so on]
FROM NameTable
INNER JOIN AdditonalTable
ON NameTable.ID=AdditionalTable.ID
WHERE [Name] = [Enter name:]
```

You can easily build this query in the query design window by adding both the tables and then dragging the ID field from one table to the next to create the join. Then just drag any fields you need into the design grid. You can the add criteria on the criteria line. `[Enter name:]` will prompt for a name, and

```
 WHERE [Name] = "Joe"
```

Will return people called Joe.

Note that Name and Time are reserved words and should not be used.

I have said `NameTable.ID`, but just `age`, this is because ID appears in both tables so it is essential to name the table, whereas `age` only occurs in one table, it would be best to name the table in this case, but you do not have to.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: hello, thanks for your help! with the query design window method, would this be the correct way to go about doing things? http://i.imgur.com/QKDwB.png there are different column names (userid instead of name, etc). The table left (details) is what contains the userid/name and the table on the right (1) has the rest of the information. Although when I did this setup, the column names are returned, but the data itself is not shown. not sure if i am just making a dumb mistake or something of the sort

Comment: It is always best to add fields rather than star (*). Don't put in `WHERE UserID=`, you only need that if you are writing your own sql, just put `[Enter user id:]` or what ever you fancy.

Answer (score 1):

You can run simply a SELECT query which looks like

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE NAME='SEARCHED_NAME';
```